# Arduino and ESP8266-01 communication issue

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266

Fix the issue why complete code are not run and nothing are showed in WiFi setting like SSID.

Pin config:

- USB to TTL Converter 3v3 - ESP8266 (VCC)
- USB to TTL Converter GND - ESP8266 (GND)
- Arduino pin 10 - ESP8266 (RX)
- Arduino pin 11 - ESP8266 (TX)
- Arduino GND - ESP8266 (CH_PD)

Now this is my code I want to connect the Android application to ESP module using WiFi after that I will be able to control relay on and off.

The code is here:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
#define LED 40
#define two 42
#define three 44
#define four 46
 SoftwareSerial esp8266(10,11); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                        // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                        // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
 void setup()
 {
   pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(two,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(three,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(four,OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different

   sendData("AT+RST\r\n",2000,DEBUG); // reset module
   sendData("AT+CWMODE=2\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure as access point
   sendData("AT+CIFSR\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // get ip address
    sendData("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // configure for multiple connections
   sendData("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n",1000,DEBUG); // turn on server on port 80

   Serial.println("server started running on socket # 192.168.4.1:80");

 }

   void loop()
    {
 if(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
 {

          String cc="";
          while(esp8266.available()){
       // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
           char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
           Serial.write(c);
       cc+=c;
     }
         Serial.print(cc);
         delay(1000);

      if(esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
      {
      delay(100);

       int connectionId = esp8266.read()-48; // subtract 48 because the read() function returns 
                                          // the ASCII decimal value and 0 (the first decimal number) starts at 48
    Serial.print("conn id = ");
    Serial.println(connectionId);

    String msg="";
    while(esp8266.available()){
      char c=esp8266.read();
      msg+=c;
    }
    Serial.print("msg = ");
    Serial.println(msg);

    String vv=msg.substring(10,16);
    Serial.print("vv = ");
    Serial.println(vv);
    vv.trim();
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     if(vv.length()>0){
      if(vv=="sw1:on"){
        Serial.println("switch 1 is turned on");
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);

      }
      if(vv=="sw1:of"){
        Serial.println("switch 1 is turned off");
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);

      }
      if(vv=="sw2:on"){
        Serial.println("switch 2 is turned on");
        digitalWrite(two,HIGH);

      }
      if(vv=="sw2:of"){
        Serial.println("switch 2 is turned off");
        digitalWrite(two,LOW);

      }
      if(vv=="sw3:on"){
        Serial.println("switch 3 is turned on");
        digitalWrite(three,HIGH);

      }
      if(vv=="sw3:of"){
        Serial.println("switch 3 is turned off");
        digitalWrite(three,LOW);

      }
      if(vv=="sw4:on"){
        Serial.println("switch 4 is turned on");
        digitalWrite(four,HIGH);

      }
      if(vv=="sw4:of"){
        Serial.println("switch 4 is turned off");
        digitalWrite(four,LOW);


      }
      if(vv=="sw_:on"){
        Serial.println("all switches are turned on");
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(two,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(three,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(four,HIGH);

      }
      if(vv=="sw_:of"){
        Serial.println("all switches are turned off");
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
        digitalWrite(two,LOW);
        digitalWrite(three,LOW);
        digitalWrite(four,LOW);

      }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    String closeCommand = "AT+CIPCLOSE="; 
    closeCommand+=connectionId; // append connection id
    closeCommand+="\r\n";

    sendData(closeCommand,3000,DEBUG);
      }
   }
 }
    String sendData(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
  {
    String response = "";
    Serial.print("command => ");
    esp8266.print(command); // send the read character to the esp8266

   long int time = millis();

    while( (time+timeout) > millis())
    {
      while(esp8266.available())
     {

   // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window 
   char c = esp8266.read(); // read the next character.
   response+=c;
     }  
  }

    if(debug)
   {
    Serial.print("response => ");
    Serial.print(response);
  }

      return response;
}
```

Comment: post your code in the form of text not as image

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the baud rate to 115200 of the esp8266 since I have found that is what is mostly used. You have not specified if you can communicate at all.

Answer (score 0):

**You may try these...**

1. Connect CH_PD with VCC then 3.3v
2. Serial.begin(115200);
3. ESP RESET to Arduino RESET